# События программно созданного объекта 1С 8.2

Tags: 1с

Добрый день. Создаю программным образом новый объект (допустим - ТабличныйДокумент)

```
&НаКлиенте
ТД = Новый ТабличныйДокумент;
```

Каким образом можно описать обработку событий это объекта (например "Выбор")?
Платформа 8.2 Управляемое приложение.

**P.S** В принципе можно открыть новую форму на которой есть объект аналогичного типа, присвоить значение нового объекта к данному, и использовать события из формы в явном виде. Меня же интересует именно программный способ описания таких событий, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обработка событий возможна только у интерфейсных объектов.